# Where JavaScript code may be located on the HTML page apart from script tags

Tags: javascript, html

I know JavaScript can be embedded into the web page using script tag, it can be in the HTML or external Js file. But as far as I understand it also can be in onclick and onload event parameters of tags. I would like to know all possible places on HTML page where JavaScript can be located and limitations which come with it, for example, is it possible to place all my JS code into onload parameter of tag?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am studying JS obfuscation.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194397/how-can-i-obfuscate-protect-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript can be found:

- In `script` tags (inline or referencing a separate resource).
- `onxyz` attribute event handlers.
- In some places URLs are expected, if prefixed with the `javascript:` pseudo-protocol:

  - The `href` on an `a` element
  - The `action` of a `form` element

Here's an example of three of those (Stack Snippets don't allow any form submissions):

```html
<script>
console.log("Code in script element");
</script>
<div onclick="console.log('Div clicked!')">Click me</div>
<a href="javascript:console.log('Link clicked')">Click me, too</a>
```

Comment: What about the limitations?

Comment: @Mr.Pricky: I've never tested limits on, say, `onload` attribute length. There's no reason to: Just use a `script` tag and call the code in it from the `onload` (or better yet: don't, the `load` event fires *very* late in the page load process).